# Create new type using reflection

Tags: vb.net

I've read over internet some relevant information that in fact .Net provides possibility to create defined new dynamic type at runtime. First i thought its great news because my current application got hard-coded enum type defined in class. What my thought was i could create that enum usinf reflection and create his enum values from XML. Unfortunetly i tried to find some good tutorial but cannot find something could explain me enough how to do that. Can you give me either some good sample or redirect me to somwhere where i can obtain some knowledge how could i achieve that?

Comment: A bit vague.  Do you want to modify/extend the enum and/or class? Could you inherit from it?  You can create a new Type using CodeDOM but if you have the code to feed to it, you should also be able to do something more direct like inherit.

Comment: i have hardcoded some values inside my enum type. I would like this values to be lets say comming from XML when application is starting and not hard coded values in enum directly. Is reflection new type would be some resolution? I could use serialization then and my reflection new type would build enum with values based on that serialized xml.

Comment: why does this need to be done with reflection (ie at runtime)? why cant you change *your* class to work the way you now want it to?

Comment: because every time i want to add some new enum value i need to go to code directly i would like to be that i have my serialized xml configuration file and every time i want to add something new i would just need to add it inside xml and not in code, because i have some class that uses enum value inside some method which i shared for very enum value. Is it possible?

Comment: no it is not possible to change enum constants using reflection or serialization because they are constants.  the compiler has to know about all of them at compile time.  It sounds like they ought not be constants at all if you want to change them via xml or some such.

Comment: what you are saying is its not possible to create enum before runtime because its static/shared (value type)? What if the new type would be reference type, does reflection could handle that task to create class type with some properties, eventually methods and initiate that cain of class? If so hows them my classes already in project could communicate with that?

Comment: the problem is that an enum is a set of constant values.  if you change to something else, like a class, collection, list, dictionary you can load/change them however you like.  Hopefully the code which previously relied on constants will now know how to do the same with variables.

Comment: do you have any helpfull code or just a simple how could i achieve that and what about already implemented normal classes within project, how could i use new dynamic class if this class is not implemented at runtime and classes dont know nothing about it?

Comment: you'd have to post some small example of what you want to be replaced.  As is, this is far to abstract to provide solutions for.

Comment: ok let me prepare and ill come back asap.